# Regexp to except trailing one space after ,

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, csv, csv-import

I am importing CSV file using javascript. My file has strings like "Advance Home Technologies, Inc.",so when I am splitting rows by "," it will also split "Advance Home Technologies" and "Inc.". So I want solution for this. Below is my code.

```
function UploadCSV() {
    var csvFileUpload = document.getElementById("csvFileUpload");
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
    if (regex.test(csvFileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var table = document.createElement("table");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                    }
                }
                var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
                dvTable.value = "";
                dvTable.appendChild(table);
                document.getElementById("table_data").value = document.getElementById("dvTable").innerHTML;
            }
            reader.readAsText(csvFileUpload.files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
        //document.getElementById("table_data").value = document.getElementById("dvTable").value;
    } else {
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the fields may contain comma's like in your example, I would suggest changing this line

```
var cells = rows[i].split(",");
```

into

```
cells = rows[i].split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
```

This will split the line on commas except when they are inside a quoted string.

Regex explanation:

```
"," +                 Match the character “,” literally
"(?=" +               Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   "(?:" +            Match the regular expression below
      "(?:" +         Match the regular expression below
         '[^"]' +     Match any character that is NOT a “"”
            "*" +     Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
         '"' +        Match the character “"” literally
      "){2}" +        Exactly 2 times
   ")*" +             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   '[^"]' +           Match any character that is NOT a “"”
      "*" +           Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   "$" +              Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
")"
```